# VBA RecordSet.RecordCount = -1 when using stored procedure and command

Tags: sql, vba, stored-procedures, command, recordset

I call a stored procedure with a command. I receive the result in a record set. Now I need to do some calculations and therefore need to know number of records that was returned. RecordSet.RecordCount should give me that but only returns -1. I have tried different values of CursorType and CursorLocation, tried MoveLast. Nothing helps.

I made a temporary solution by assuming a fixed number for the number of records.

There are many threads here about RecordCount, and also articles, that I read but nothing seems to help. Is the problem that I use a command? Most examples I see dont use commands.

I am an experienced programmer but not so used to SQL and VBA. Anyone who can give me some help?

Best Regards,
Wolfgang

```
Sub CallStoredProcedure()

Dim Conn As ADODB.Connection, RecordSet As ADODB.RecordSet

Dim Command As ADODB.Command
Dim ConnectionString As String, StoredProcName As String
Dim LoginID As ADODB.Parameter, Entity_Id As ADODB.Parameter

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set Conn = New ADODB.Connection
Set RecordSet = New ADODB.RecordSet
Set Command = New ADODB.Command

'w
RecordSet.CursorType = adOpenStatic
RecordSet.CursorLocation = adUseClient


ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=HIQARBL218\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=SweSalaryStore;Trusted_Connection=yes;"

On Error GoTo CloseConnection

Conn.Open ConnectionString

StoredProcName = "dbo.getInfoFromSQLDB"

With Command
    .ActiveConnection = Conn
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    .CommandText = StoredProcName
End With

Set EMPNR = Command.CreateParameter("@EMPNR", adVarChar, adParamInput, 100, "107")
Command.Parameters.Append EMPNR

Set PERNR = Command.CreateParameter("@PERNR", adVarChar, adParamInput, 100, "1111110008")
Command.Parameters.Append PERNR

Set CMPNR = Command.CreateParameter("@CMPNR", adVarChar, adParamInput, 100, "5612")
Command.Parameters.Append CMPNR

Set PERIODFROM = Command.CreateParameter("@PERIODFROM", adVarChar, adParamInput, 100, "1001")
Command.Parameters.Append PERIODFROM

Set PERIODTO = Command.CreateParameter("@PERIODTO", adVarChar, adParamInput, 100, "1701")
Command.Parameters.Append PERIODTO

Set RecordSet = Command.Execute


Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A5").CopyFromRecordset RecordSet


'loop to get column headings.
For i = 0 To RecordSet.Fields.Count - 1
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, i + 1).Value = RecordSet.Fields(i).Name
Next i


'Calculate last row in RecordSet
Dim lastRow As Integer
lastRow = 2000
'lastRow = RecordSet.RecordCount 'NOT WORKING!!!

'Average OB
Dim AvgOB As Double
AvgOB = Excel.WorksheetFunction.Average(Range(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(5, 2), Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(lastRow, 2)))
AvgOB = Excel.WorksheetFunction.Round(AvgOB, 2)
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 2).Value = AvgOB
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, 2).Value = AvgOB * 12


RecordSet.Close
Conn.Close
On Error GoTo 0
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Exit Sub

CloseConnection:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "SQL Stored Procedure Did Not Execute Sucessfully!", vbCritical, "SQL Error"
    Conn.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You've done

```
 Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A5").CopyFromRecordset RecordSet
```

so at that point the number of records returned is the number of rows occupied from a5 down:

```
 Dim lastrow as long  'not integer!
 lastrow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A5").currentregion.rows.count + 4
```

the plus four is  since you start at row 5